# Swift 5 : What's 'Escaping closure captures mutating 'self' parameter' and how to fix it

Tags: swift, api, struct, closures

Hello guys I'm trying to make a simple and re-usable Swift Network Layer

Maybe it's not the best way to loop returned data in view but after I tried to get the returned Api data to Loop it in SwiftUI view I'm getting error :

```
Escaping closure captures mutating 'self' parameter
```

And don't know where or what i missed in this lesson

and here's a picture of the file

[image]

ContentView.swift

```
struct ContentView: View {

    var emptyDataArr: [CollectionItem] = []

    init() {
        ServiceLayer.request(router: Router.getSources) { (result: Result<[String : [CollectionItem]], Error>) in
            switch result {
            case .success(let data):
                print(data)
                self.emptyDataArr = data["custom_collections"]!

            case .failure:
                print(result)
            }
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack (alignment: .leading) {
            Text("No thing yet")
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

ServiceLayer Class `ServiceLayer.swift`

```
class ServiceLayer {
    // 1.
    class func request<T: Codable>(router: Router, completion: @escaping (Result<[String: [T]], Error>) -> ()) {
        // 2.
        var components = URLComponents()
        components.scheme = router.scheme
        components.host = router.host
        components.path = router.path
        components.queryItems = router.parameters
        // 3.
        guard let url = components.url else { return }
        var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
        urlRequest.httpMethod = router.method
        // 4.
        let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
        let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { data, response, error in
            // 5.
            guard error == nil else {
                completion(.failure(error!))
                print(error?.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
            guard response != nil else {
                return
            }
            guard let data = data else {
                return
            }
            print(data)
            // 6.
            let responseObject = try! JSONDecoder().decode([String: [T]].self, from: data)
            // 7.
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                // 8.
                completion(.success(responseObject))
            }
        }
        dataTask.resume()
    }
}
```

Comment: This depends on the signature of `ServiceLayer.request()`. I assume its parameter includes a protocol of some kind?

Comment: I updated the question already may you check it again I add Servicelayer class content @RobNapier

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The problem is that `ContentView` is a struct, which means it's a value type. You can't pass that to a closure and mutate it. If you did, nothing would change, because the closure would have its own independent copy of the struct.

Your problem is that you've mixed your View and your Model. There can be many, many copies of a given View (every time it's passed to a function, a copy is made). You wouldn't want every one of those copies to initiate a request. Instead move this request logic into a Model object and just let the View observe it.

Comment: Can you give an example of it using the above code?

Answer (score 14):

Simply move the call from inside `init` to inside an `onAppear` somewhere in the `body`

Comment: This is such an underrated comment that saved me a lot of time today. Thanks Garrett!

Comment: lol this is so funny. Do this in JS all the time but swift... well at least they're careful! Apple is so interesting with regards to software.  They make the best hardware, no stone left unturned, but I get the feeling their dev tools aren't so highly prioritized. But I appreciate them moving to swift, it's much better than Objective C!

Answer (score 7):

I ran into the same problem today and found this post, and then I followed [@Rob Napier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/97337/rob-napier)'s suggestion, and finally made a working example.

Hope the following code can help (Note: it does not directly answer your question, but I think it will help as an example):

```
import Combine
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport

let url = URL(string: "https://source.unsplash.com/random")!

// performs a network request to fetch a random image from Unsplash’s public API
func imagePub() -> AnyPublisher<Image?, Never> {
    URLSession.shared
        .dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
        .map { data, _ in Image(uiImage: UIImage(data: data)!)}
        .print("image")
        .replaceError(with: nil)
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    // model
    @Published var image: Image?
    
    // simulate user taps on a button
    let taps = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()
    
    var subscriptions = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    
    init() {
        taps
            // ⭐️ map the tap to a new network request
            .map { _ in imagePub() }
            // ⭐️ accept only the latest tap
            .switchToLatest()
            .assign(to: \.image, on: self)
            .store(in: &subscriptions)
    }
    
    func getImage() {
        taps.send()
    }
    
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    // view model
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = ViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            viewModel.image?
                .resizable().scaledToFit().frame(height: 400).border(Color.black)
            Button(action: {
                self.viewModel.getImage()
            }, label: {
                Text("Tap")
                    .padding().foregroundColor(.white)
                    .background(Color.pink).cornerRadius(12)
            })
        }.padding().background(Color.gray)
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(ContentView())
```

Before tapping the button, the `ContentView` looks like this:

[image: before tapping]

After tapping the button (and wait for a few seconds), it looks like this:

[image: after tapping]

So I know it's working ^_^

Comment: Thank you for the example! Was a pain. Placing the network layer INSIDE the view model is awesome