# How to toggle a boolean value using timer in Swift

Tags: swift

I have a boolean called 'isMatched'. It is written in my Model. I use this boolean to show a view on a certain state of the view. However, I want the view to get hidden automatically after 0.5 second. I tried to use DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter and also Timer, but always got error "Escaping closure captures mutating 'self' parameter". I have copied my Model below. Please advice me a solution.

I made the boolean var 'isMatched' true in the 'choose()' function.

```
import Foundation

struct WordMatchingGameModel<CardContent> {
    private(set) var cards: Array<Card>
    private(set) var words: Array<Word>
    private(set) var gameDataSet: Array<String>
    private(set) var matchedWord: String = ""
    var isMatched: Bool = false
    private var colors: [[String]] = [["AeroBlue", "AeroBlue"], ["BlueBell", "BlueBell"], ["PinkLavender", "PinkLavender"], ["Opal", "Opal"], ["CornflowerBlue", "CornflowerBlue"]]

    mutating func choose(card: Card) {
        if let choosenIndex = cards.firstIndex(matching: card) {
            if !cards[choosenIndex].isTapped {
                cards[choosenIndex].isTapped = true
                cards[choosenIndex].bgColors = numberOfMatchedWords == 0 ? colors[0] : numberOfMatchedWords == 1 ? colors[1] : colors[2]
                words.append(Word(id: cards[choosenIndex].id, content: cards[choosenIndex].content))
                print(word)
                if match() {
                    for index in 0..<cards.count {
                        if cards[index].isTapped { cards[index].isDisabled = true }
                    }
                    numberOfMatchedWords += 1
                    score += 10
                    matchedWord = word
                    isMatched = true
                    delay(interval: 0.5) {
                        self.isMatched = false
                    }
                    words.removeAll()
                }
            } else {
                cards[choosenIndex].isTapped = false
                cards[choosenIndex].bgColors = ["GradientEnd", "GradientStart"]
                var tempWords = Array<Word>()
                
                for index in 0..<words.count {
                    if words[index].id != cards[choosenIndex].id { tempWords.append(words[index]) }
                }
                words = tempWords
            }
        }
    }
    
    func delay(interval: TimeInterval, closure: @escaping () -> Void) {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + interval, execute: closure)
    }
    
    func match() -> Bool {
        for index in 0..<gameDataSet.count {
            if gameDataSet[index] == word {
                return true
            }
        }
        return false
    }
    var word: String {
        var array = Array<Character>()
        
        for index in 0..<words.count {
            array.append(words[index].content as! Character)
        }
        return String(array).capitalized
    }
    private(set) var numberOfMatchedWords: Int = 0
    private(set) var score: Int = 0
    
    init(numberOfCards: Int, gameDataSet: Array<String>, cardContentFactory: (Int) -> CardContent) {
        cards = Array<Card>()
        words = Array<Word>()
        self.gameDataSet = gameDataSet
        for index in 0..<numberOfCards {
            let content = cardContentFactory(index)
            self.cards.append(Card(id: index + 1, content: content))
        }
        cards.shuffle()
        colors.shuffle()
    }
    
    struct Card: Identifiable {
        var id: Int
        var content: CardContent
        var bgColors: [String] = ["GradientEnd", "GradientStart"]
        var isTapped: Bool = false
        var isDisabled: Bool = false
    }
    struct Word: Identifiable {
        var id: Int
        var content: CardContent
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: use class instead of struct for WordMatchingGameModel. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58327013/swift-5-whats-escaping-closure-captures-mutating-self-parameter-and-how-t/58327871

Comment: Thanks Ezaji. It works fine now. However, my whole view got very slow in response after converting struct into class. Is it a recognised issue?

Comment: Probably due to delay?) I need more info to be more helpful)

Answer (score 0):

Create a reference for self inside the function and use that instant of self inside the delay function.

```
   mutating func choose(card: Card) {
          var createReference = self
                    ....................
                    delay(interval: 0.5) {
                        createReference.isMatched = false
                    }
  }
```