# How do you reference a mutable object within an escaping closure?

Tags: swift, closures

I've read various Q&As on this topic in stack overflow, but can't seem to figure this one out. How do I reference a mutable variable in a completion handler (so that I can access it's property's value at the time that the completion handler is eventually called, *not* when it is captured) while avoiding the "Escaping closure captures mutating 'self' parameter" error?

```
let obj = MyClass(name: "myName", completion: {
    someObject.someProperty // assuming "someObject" is mutable
})
```

Comment: You may have to give us a slightly more complete (and, ideally, slightly less abstract) example of what you’re trying to do. But in short, your error message sounds like you’re trying to access a property of a value type (e.g. a `struct`) from within an escaping closure, a concept that only makes sense when dealing with reference types (e.g. a `class`). There are a variety of ways of addressing that, but it depends entirely upon the broader problem you’re trying to solve. But there’s not enough here for us to go on.

Comment: If you search for [“Escaping closure captures mutating”](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22Escaping+closure+captures+mutating%22) you’ll find tons of discussions (and you’ll see that the particulars of the answer vary greatly depending upon the broader context). For general discussion, perhaps reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58327013/swift-5-whats-escaping-closure-captures-mutating-self-parameter-and-how-t.